# Paid version of minecraft, no account?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My ex-boyfriend bought Minecraft and connect it with my account. However, when we broke up, he disconnect his account from my account. I've been trying to change my skin, but it says I have to have a minecraft.com account. Am I going to have to purchase it and then re-download it?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "*put it on my account*"? If it's your *email*, you could ask him to change it to his own. But yes, you'll have to purchase Minecraft, since you don't own it.

Comment: Sorry, I meant computer.

Comment: You pretty much have to re-purchase it and login with your new account. You don't need to re-download the game. Just log out and log in with the new account you bought it from.

Comment: Not really clear what do you mean by _put it on my account_ . But, you will need to repurchase, but not redownload if you already have Minecraft, just login with your new account.

Comment: If it was HIS account and he letted you login on your computer, then you probably don't have any chance to use it. Talk to him how it is. :)

Answer (score 1):

There are more possible answers:

- Reconnect it. Make a deal with your guy.
- Buy a new account. That's what accounts are made for.
- Don't do anything (Missing ugly smiley here). Play the demo all the time or don't play MC.

So, you need to be logged into a account - Your friends, or your own new one.

Comment: you forgot to add, You can also watch a "Lets Play"

Comment: @Fennekin playing the demo all the time is better...

Comment: nope lets play is more enjoyable then the demo. If you don't know hermitcraft then give it a try.

Comment: @Fennekin my small sister (7 or 8 yrs) always puts LP's on max volume all the time, so I disagree :D